# c# Send dictionary from user control to another form

Tags: c#, list, class, dictionary

I am not sure if my title is correct, here is my situation. I have processData class, and in it i save some data in dictionary called tradeHistory.

Now, i have user control, and after i fetch some data, i call and display that user control multiple times.

On that user control, i have button, that should display a list of data saved in dictionary that is mentioned above.

I figured i will make one more form, name it tradingHistoryForm, and add that dictionary to the list of parameters it accepts, then display that dictionary as list, but i don't know how to reference that dictionary in user control that i mentioned above.

This is my code in user control:

```
 private void viewTradeHistoryBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     tradingHistoryForm tradingHistoryF = new tradingHistoryForm(_tradingInstrumentCode,) //dictionary goes here);
     tradingHistoryF.Show();
}
```

Comment: You can declare a public property for a user control that can be set from wherever you like.

Comment: That seems to be exactly what i need, but there is one potential problem. My application will potentially have thousands of user controls, so if i set this value for every one, it will be pretty big waste of memory? It would be better if i could somehow pass reference to the original class?

Comment: If the type of the property you create on the user control is the original class, you can pass that one object reference into all your controls.

Comment: Also, if you just have one big shared instance, make it a global static and it can be accessed anywhere. Just be careful with that sort of pattern, it can cause trouble (threading concerns etc).  =)  The same sort of issue might occur if you pass the same instance of an object to multiple controls, as it would be a reference and you might have to worry about threading or concurrency issues.